# error marking master: timed out waiting for the condition [kubernetes]

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, virtualbox

Just I am starting to learn Kubernetes. I've installed CentOS 7.5 with SELinux disabled kubectl, kubeadm and kubelet by Kubernetes YUM repository.

However, when I want to start a `kubeadm init` command. I get this error message:

```
[init] using Kubernetes version: v1.12.2
[preflight] running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING Firewalld]: firewalld is active, please ensure ports [6443 10250] are open or your cluster may not function correctly
[preflight/images] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight/images] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight/images] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[kubelet] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[preflight] Activating the kubelet service
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated etcd/ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated etcd/peer certificate and key.
[certificates] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [vps604805.ovh.net localhost] and IPs [51.75.201.75 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certificates] Generated apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated etcd/server certificate and key.
[certificates] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [vps604805.ovh.net localhost] and IPs [127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certificates] Generated etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated ca certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated apiserver certificate and key.
[certificates] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [vps604805.ovh.net kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 51.75.201.75]
[certificates] Generated apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key.
[certificates] valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[certificates] Generated sa key and public key.
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf"
[controlplane] wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-apiserver to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[controlplane] wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-controller-manager to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
[controlplane] wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-scheduler to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
[etcd] Wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd instance to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml"
[init] waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as Static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests" 
[init] this might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled
[apiclient] All control plane components are healthy after 26.003496 seconds
[uploadconfig] storing the configuration used in ConfigMap "kubeadm-config" in the "kube-system" Namespace
[kubelet] Creating a ConfigMap "kubelet-config-1.12" in namespace kube-system with the configuration for the kubelets in the cluster
[markmaster] Marking the node vps604805.ovh.net as master by adding the label "node-role.kubernetes.io/master=''"
[markmaster] Marking the node vps604805.ovh.net as master by adding the taints [node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule]
error marking master: timed out waiting for the condition
```

According to Linux Foundation course, I don't need more command to execute to create my first start cluster into my VM.

Wrong?

Firewalld does have open ports into firewall. 6443/tcp and 10248-10252

Comment: Have you tried to debug output on more advanced level `kubeadm init -v 9`? What about `kubelet` service: `systemctl status kubelet -l`? I don't see here that you have passed `--pod-network-cidr` option for `kubeadm init` command for further [Pod network](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) installation.

Comment: This is the output https://paste.fedoraproject.org/ you get a lot of error 404 in JSON all the time. (output cut)

Comment: `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.0.0.0/16`

Comment: `systemctl status kubelet.service -l` https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/hGilqxoKPYqSYNRTP6M4og

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend to bootstrap Kubernetes cluster as guided in the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/). I've proceeded with some steps to build cluster on the same CentOS version `CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)` and will share them with you, hope it can be helpful to you to get rid of the issue during installation.

First wipe your current cluster installation:

```
# kubeadm reset -f && rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/
```

Add Kubernetes repo for further `kubeadm`, `kubelet`, `kubectl` installation:

```
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
exclude=kube*
EOF
```

Check whether `SELinux` is in permissive mode:

```
# getenforce
Permissive
```

Ensure `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` is set to 1 in your sysctl:

```
# cat <<EOF >  /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
EOF
sysctl --system
```

Install required Kubernetes components and start services:

```
# yum update && yum upgrade && yum install -y docker kubelet kubeadm kubectl --disableexcludes=kubernetes

# systemctl start docker kubelet && systemctl enable docker kubelet
```

Deploy the cluster via `kubeadm`:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

I prefer to install `Flannel` as the main `CNI` in my cluster, although there are some prerequisites for proper [Pod network](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) installation, I've passed `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` flag to `kubeadm init` command.

Create Kubernetes Home directory for your user and store `config` file:

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
$ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
$ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Install Pod network, in my case it was `Flannel`:

`$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`

Finally check Kubernetes core Pods status:

`$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-4x7zq             1/1     Running   0          36m
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-666jm             1/1     Running   0          36m
kube-system   etcd-centos-7-5                      1/1     Running   0          35m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-centos-7-5            1/1     Running   0          35m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-centos-7-5   1/1     Running   0          35m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-2bmw9          1/1     Running   0          33m
kube-system   kube-proxy-pcgw8                     1/1     Running   0          36m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-centos-7-5            1/1     Running   0          35m
```

In case you still have any doubts, just write down a comment below this answer.

Comment: ¡Thanks that's works! :D I just only solved problem with authentications but that's it's another post or research info.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the following issue in kubernetes

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1092

The workaround is to provide `--node-name=<hostname>` .  Just go through the above ticket for more info. Hope this helps

EDIT:
I have the same issue in kubeadm-1.10.0
After removing --hostname-override from /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf file, atleast able to initialize cluster. Didn't give provide --node-name in my cluster

Comment: I've added master.vps604805.ovh.net or do kubeadm reset and try with just only vps604805.ovh.net and It's get same error.

`kubernetes-cni-0.6.0-0.x86_64
kubelet-1.12.2-0.x86_64
kubectl-1.12.2-0.x86_64
kubeadm-1.12.2-0.x86_64`
It's interesting this msg when I try to execute kubectl version:

`The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`
`This port is open.

Comment: Edited my answer, try that

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. In [/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/HzeHo6KwONShx~EODO2nFg) I don't have `--hostname-override`

Comment: Could you also remove node-name option ? Kubernetes is going to change the timeout way in 1.13, they have acknowledged it. Till then if we can find a workaround for this

Comment: Yes, I've tried to create cluster without `--node-name` but I get the same error.

Comment: ```$kubectl get pods --all-namespaces```
core-dns is in "pending" state.
```$kubectl get node```
Master is in "NotReady" state.
 NotReady   control-plane,master   3m26s   v1.21.0

Answer (score 1):

In some systems, particularly on older Ubuntu releases, this issue can be solved by getting a slightly older version of the k8s master components, namely `kubectl`, `kubeadm` and `kubelet`.

To do so, remove your current setup with:

```
sudo kubeadm reset
sudo rm -rf /etc/kubernetes
sudo apt-get remove kubectl kubeadm kubelet
```

Then, reinstall with version `1.20.2-00`:

```
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet=1.20.2-00 kubeadm=1.20.2-00 kubectl=1.20.2-00
```