# Facing issue while trying to install Kubernetes [ubuntu18 image on openstack]

Tags: kubernetes, openstack-nova

Since yesterday, I am struggling with this strange issue: node "kmaster" not found.
[image: img_1]

I tried with multiple combinations of installing kubernetes on jetstream instance.

1. using calico in ubuntu
2. using flannel in centos
3. and few other ways

I looked it online and found many people have the same issue:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61277
[image: [kubeissue_2.jpg]]

If someone ran into a similar issue, then please let me know what steps are needed to be taken to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you K8s components running on the master?  `docker ps` on the master.  Do you see the kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, kube-proxy?

Comment: @Rico yes I can see those components running successfully on master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my solution for this. I was having issue running kubernetes cluster because the kubernetes components are distributed on multiple servers. Once I created the master node and slave(worker) node on the same machine, the issue got resolved.
The steps that I took to resolve the issue:
1. on slave/worker machine, run this command: kubeadm reset
2. on master node, generate the token by running this command: kubeadm generate token.
3. use the token generated in master machine on the slave node, so that the node machine can join the kubernetes cluster.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to bootstrap Kubernetes cluster from scratch and share with you some helpful links with steps how to proceed:

- [Kubernetes cluster install on Ubuntu with Calico CNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720380/kubernetes-api-server-is-not-starting-on-a-single-kubeadm-cluster)
- [Kubernetes cluster install on Centos with Flannel CNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383994/error-marking-master-timed-out-waiting-for-the-condition-kubernetes/53410468#53410468)

Keep in mind to fulfill system [requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin) before you start with `kubeadm` installation procedure.

You can also take a look at the general `kubeadm` installation or runtime [troubleshooting guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/).

Comment: I have followed the documentation properly even then the issue wasn't resolved. Once I created the master and slave on the same docker image.. it resolved the issue.